# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str' (python)

Tags: python

I really need help here. I am very new to python (in fact I started yesterday) and I keep getting this message:

> **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'**

when trying this:

```
age = input()
year = (2016-age)
print (year)
```

Please make your answers simple because I'm new.

Comment: If you have been learning Python for a single day, you should still be reading tutorials and guides.

Answer (score 4):

`input` function returns a string, so you have a string in your `age` variable.
you cannot substract a string from an integer, so you have to convert your string into an integer with the `int` function.

```
age = int(input())
```

Comment: To be specific `input()` return string in Python 3, not in Python 2. It is same as `raw_input()` in python 2